# Triggering a Link in a Div on Div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have an href link in a card div that creates a modal pop-up with all the information I need for a project. i'm currently trying to trigger the click even on that link whenever any part of the div is clicked. This is for a school assignment so I can only use Vanilla JS and JQuery. the card class is the div and the extra class is the link to click.

I've seen 'stop propagation' for these type of events but that's not quite what 'm looking for.

```
$(".card").click(function(){
    $(this).$(".extra").trigger('click');
    });
```

I get an error from the code at .$(".extra") trying to find the instance of the extra class in the specific div.

Comment: `$(this).find('.extra')`

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```js
$('.card').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.extra').trigger('click');
});
```